# binary tree in C - multiple data

Tags: c, binary, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I need to create a binary search tree that will store many members of contest.

```
typedef struct Member{
char name[30];
char surname[30];
int id;
char email[30];
}member;
```

A key used to add nodes is name (alphabetic order). I understand that I need to use **strcmp** to define where to put a new member, but I don't know how to implement a tree. Should my struct look like that:

```
typedef struct Member{
char name[30];
char surname[30];
int id;
char email[30];
struct mnode *left; 
struct mnode *right;
}member;
```

Or should I keep the old struct and create a struct for nodes and just pass a pointer to member as data type like that:

```
typedef struct mnode { 
    struct member *aMember; 
    struct tnode *left; 
    struct tnode *right;
} MTree;
```

If so, is it correct? :

```
MTree* addMember(MTree* nodeP, char name, char surname, int id, char email){
    if( nodeP == NULL )
    {
        nodeP = (struct tnode*) malloc( sizeof( struct mnode ) );
        (nodeP->mBook)->name = name;
        (nodeP->mBook)->surname = surname;
        (nodeP->mBook)->id = id;
        (nodeP->mBook)->email = email;

        /* initialize the children to null */
        (nodeP)->left = NULL;    
        (nodeP)->right = NULL;  
    }
    else if(name > (nodeP->aBook)->name)
    {
        addMember(&(nodeP)->left,name,surname,id,email);
    }
    else if(year < (nodeP->aBook)->year)
    {
        addMember(&(nodeP)->right,name,surname,id,email);
    }
    return nodeP;
}
```

Comment: Either struct is fine. As for "is it correct": The way to determine that is to test the code. As it is, you don't really have any specific question. I encourage you to continue with your work by testing your code. If you hit an actual problem then come back to show your code as a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and ask a question about a specific problem.

Comment: Also, please note that you can edit your original question. So put any updates/changes into the question itself and not as comments.

Comment: Note that names usually have more than a single letter; you need to use `char *name` and `char *surname` in the function signature.  You also need to use `strcpy()` or equivalent to copy names into the structure — plain assignments don't work.

Comment: Note too that `&(nodeP)->left` is the same as `&(nodeP->left)` and is most conventionally written `&nodeP->left` — no parentheses needed.

Answer (score 0):

If coded correctly, either the augmented structure or the additional structure technique can be used — both work, and each can be necessary on occasion.

However, the qualifier 'if coded correctly' is crucial.  Your first augmented structure is shown as:

```
typedef struct Member
{
    char name[30];
    char surname[30];
    int id;
    char email[30];
    struct mnode *left; 
    struct mnode *right;
} member;
```

At this point, there is no `struct mnode` already known, so you have pointers to two structures that are not anything to do with the member structure.  You need either:

```
typedef struct Member
{
    char name[30];
    char surname[30];
    int id;
    char email[30];
    struct Member *left; 
    struct Member *right;
} member;
```

or:

```
typedef struct Member member;

struct Member
{
    char name[30];
    char surname[30];
    int id;
    char email[30];
    member *left; 
    member *right;
};
```

Both work; there isn't a strong case for one over the other — but the second lends itself to 'opaque data types' when you want them.

Similarly, you have:

```
typedef struct mnode { 
    struct member *aMember; 
    struct tnode *left; 
    struct tnode *right;
} MTree;
```

There is no type `struct member` shown yet (there is a `struct Member` — remember, C is case-sensitive), nor is there a `struct tnode`.  This structure is useless as it stands, but if corrected to:

```
typedef struct mnode
{ 
    struct Member *aMember; 
    struct mnode  *left; 
    struct mnode  *right;
} MTree;
```

then it could be used for a tree of the original `struct Member` structure (the one with no pointers in it).  You could also do without the pointer to member using:

```
typedef struct mnode
{ 
    struct Member aMember; 
    struct mnode *left; 
    struct mnode *right;
} MTree;
```

The advantage of this is that there is one less chunk of memory to allocate and free; it simplifies the bookkeeping.

You must keep structure tags and typedef names properly under control.  There is no reason to invent new names the whole time.  You can use:

```
typedef struct Tag Tag;
```

or:

```
typedef struct Tag { …structure definition… } Tag;
```

and then `struct Tag` and `Tag` both refer to the same type. The namespace for structure (and union and enumeration) tags is separate from the ordinary identifiers namespace (which is the namespace for typedef names). C++ provides this automatically; you have to do it manually in C, as shown.  The Linux kernel coding guidelines do not allow typedefs for structure types — you must always write `struct WhatEver` and not create names like `typedef struct WhatEver WhatEver;` or `typedef struct WhatEver WhatIsIt;`.  You don't have to follow the Linux guidelines in your own code — I don't — but they are not wholly without merit.